# Scala random date between two dates

Tags: java, scala, date

I am trying to write a method which takes two `java.util.Date`'s as parameters and returns a random `java.util.Date` between these two in Scala. However, I get the same dummy result each time. What is wrong with my code?

#### Note:

`randomDateBetween(new Date(2017, 1, 1), new Date(2018, 1, 1))` returns `Tue Jun 12 09:36:00 EET 3917` like all the time

#### Code:

```
 def randomDateBetween( firstDate : Date, secondDate : Date) : Date =
  {
    val ratio = new Random().nextInt(100);

    val difference = (secondDate.getTime - firstDate.getTime)

    val surplusMillis = (difference * (ratio / 100.0)).asInstanceOf[Long]
    
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()

    cal.setTimeInMillis(surplusMillis + firstDate.getTime)

    return cal.getTime()
  }
```

I fixed it guys, thank you anyway. Cause of the error was java.util.Date being deprecated. I changed my method call like this and it worked perfectly fine:

```
val date1 = Calendar.getInstance
val date2 = Calendar.getInstance

date1.set(2017, 1, 1)
date2.set(2018, 1, 1)

randomDateBetween(date1.getTime, date2.getTime)
```

Comment: It's not that it is deprecated, it's that you don't read the doc: " year    the year minus 1900."

Answer (score 3):

You need to seed the Random object like so:

```
Random.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis())
val ratio = new Random().nextInt(100)
```

Answer (score 2):

(Java syntax here, rather than Scala)

## `ThreadLocalRandom`

The [Answer by sheunis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45091103/642706) is correct but outdated.

Another outdated option is `Math.random`.

```
randomNum = minimum + ( int )( Math.random() * maximum );
```

The modern approach since Java 7 is [`ThreadLocalRandom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt-int-int-). See this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/363692/642706).

```
long random = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong( minimum , maximum + 1 );
```

Both of these alternatives to `Random` are initialized with an internally generated seed that may not otherwise be modified.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes.

Also you are using troublesome old date-time classes `Date` and `Calendar` that are now legacy, supplanted by java.time classes.

## Using java.time

For date-only values without time-of-day and without time zone, use `LocalDate` class.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.JANUARY , 1 ) ;
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 1 ) ;
```

Count days between, to determine random number of days.

```
long maxDays = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( start , stop ) ;
```

So we want to add a random number of days, as little as zero and as much as `maxDays`.

```
long days = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong( 0 , maxDays + 1 );

LocalDate ld = start.plusDays( days ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Date randomDate= new Date(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(fromDate.getTime(), toDate.getTime()+1));
```

I don't know much about scala. I have tested it in java, I think this solution is applicable for scala as well. Please modify the code if needed.